# I am getting tje error "java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1" in scala

Tags: scala

scala:

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("1.pdf").getLines
```

> java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Comment: If '1.pdf' is actually a PDF file, it most likely contains binary parts. But you attempt to obtain a list of Strings, which requires that the file can be parsed with a given encoding.

Comment: Thnk you Helios. than how can i calculate the lines in a pdf file?

Comment: There is no easy way to do this without using some 3rd party library. If you absolutely want to do it yourself, refer to the official PDF specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How important is it to read *lines* ? Because in a pdf, to me, it doesn't make much sense : you're reading binary data. So a safe bet would be

```
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}
val byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("1.pdf"))
```